compare comma seperated strings if there is the same number in them
I have two strings the first one looks like this: 24,36,78,98
the second one like this: 25,36,88,98
Now what i want to do is to compare the two strings in sql and only return the numbers that are the same in each string.
Is this possible in sql or do i have to write my own function in like PL/SQL?
I googled but could not find any answers to this question.

This can be done in sql or pl/sql depending on your needs:
plsql
If you have Oracle APEX installed in your db you have the APEX_STRING api that you can use to convert the string to an array. Then use the MULTISET operator to get the intersect of the values:
set serveroutput on size 999999
clear screen
DECLARE
  l_string1 VARCHAR2(100) :=  '24,36,78,98';
  l_string2 VARCHAR2(100) :=  '25,36,88,98';
  l_string_intersect VARCHAR2(100);
  l_string1_arr apex_t_varchar2;
  l_string2_arr apex_t_varchar2;
  l_intersect_arr  apex_t_varchar2;
BEGIN 
  l_string1_arr :=  apex_string.split(l_string1,',');
  l_string2_arr :=  apex_string.split(l_string2,',');
  l_intersect_arr := l_string1_arr MULTISET INTERSECT l_string2_arr;
  l_string_intersect := apex_string.join(l_intersect_arr,',');
  dbms_output.put_line('intersect values: '||l_string_intersect);
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.



intersect values: 36,98

Without APEX and if you still want pl/sql, then use a sql technique to split (see below) and use the MULTISET operator to get the intersect.
sql
for sql, have a look at this blog on the various methods to split a comma separated string into values.
Here is an example of how to do it using a technique described in the blog above:
with 
string1 as (
  select '24,36,78,98' str from dual
),
string2 as (
  select '25,36,88,98' str from dual
), 
string1_tab as (
  select regexp_substr (
           str,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           level
         ) value
  from   string1
  connect by level <= 
    length ( str ) - length ( replace ( str, ',' ) ) + 1
),
string2_tab as (
  select regexp_substr (
           str,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           level
         ) value
  from   string2
  connect by level <= 
    length ( str ) - length ( replace ( str, ',' ) ) + 1
)
select * from string1_tab
INTERSECT
select * from string2_tab
;


Yet another option (looks quite simple), which splits string into rows so that you'd be able to apply the intersect set operator.
Sample data:
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select '24,36,78,98', '25,36,88,98' from dual)

Query begins here:
  3  select regexp_substr(col1, '[^,]+', 1, level) val
  4    from test
  5    connect by level <= regexp_count(col1, ',') + 1
  6  intersect
  7  select regexp_substr(col2, '[^,]+', 1, level) val
  8    from test
  9    connect by level <= regexp_count(col2, ',') + 1;

VAL
-----------
36
98

SQL>


Yet another one with XQuery:
with data(a,b) as (
    select '24,36,78,98', '25,36,88,98' from dual
)
select t.* from 
data d,
xmltable( 
  'for $i in (ora:tokenize($X,",")), $j in (ora:tokenize($Y,",")) where ($i = $j) return $i'
  passing a as "X", b as "Y"
  columns val number path '.'
) t
;

Your imagination is the only limit to invent others...
With 23c you can even use MLE to play with Javascript function on JSON arrays:
export function intersect(arr1string, arr2string) {
    let arr1 = eval(arr1string == null? [] : arr1string);
    let arr2 = eval(arr2string == null? [] : arr2string);
    return arr1.filter(n => arr2.includes(n));
}

